# Real world code examples about usage of four special slots of Qt Test

Tags: qt, qttest

I am studying about Qt Test and got to know there are four special slots which are executed before and after test cases.

> 1. initTestCase() will be called before the first testfunction is executed.
> 2. cleanupTestCase() will be called after the last testfunction was executed.
> 3. init() will be called before each testfunction is executed.
> 4. cleanup() will be called after every testfunction.

I know how to use them as a clear example is there in Qt Documentation.

But my problem here is I want to see **real world usage**, not printing an example qDebug, of those slots. What can be changed within those slots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for my own question [here](https://sites.google.com/a/embeddedlab.org/community/technical-articles/qt/qt-posts/creatingandexecutingasingletestprojectwithmultipleunittests).

> Try to always do the initTestCase() and cleanupTestCase() methods, so
> they can be executed at the startup and at the end of the test. Those
> methods usually are to create and delete objects, as you can see in
> the example. If you don't create them, they will be “executed” anyway
> but will do nothing.

```
#ifndef CIRCLETEST_H

#define CIRCLETEST_H

#include <QObject>

#include <QtTest/QtTest>

#include "../Geometry/circle.h"

class CircleTest : public QObject

{

  Q_OBJECT

public:

  explicit CircleTest(QObject *parent = 0);

private:

  Circle *c1;

  Circle *c2;

private slots:

  void initTestCase();

  void testRadius();

  void testArea();

  void cleanupTestCase();

};

#endif // CIRCLETEST_H
```

circle.h

```
#include "circletest.h"

CircleTest::CircleTest(QObject *parent) :

  QObject(parent)

{

}

void CircleTest::initTestCase()

{

  c1 = new Circle();

  c2 = new Circle(10);

}

void CircleTest::testArea()

{

  QCOMPARE(c1->getArea(), 3.14);

  QCOMPARE(c2->getArea(), 314.0);

}

void CircleTest::testRadius()

{

  QCOMPARE(c1->getRadius(), 1.0);

  QCOMPARE(c2->getRadius(), 10.0);

}

void CircleTest::cleanupTestCase()

{

  delete c1;

  delete c2;

}
```